# White spots / pits on Jade leaves

Tags: leaves, jade

Little white / light brown pits all over my Jade plant’s leaves. Anyone know what might cause this? Is it normal and I’ve never noticed before? :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like mechanical damage, where something has punctured the surface of the leaf, a few cells have died and bled sap in that area then dried up and left the mark. A nibble by a curious cat, a brush-by when the leaf was young and fragile, a knock while transplanting, many causes are possible. The plant looks healthy, and the vulnerable points on the plant are not at the leaf tips but at the joints with the stem and the root ball, so keep the plant on the dry side and it should be able to look after itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like sunburn to me, but hopefully someone else can chime in and confirm this. I know that sometimes damage caused by pests can look a little like sunburn.